# Evaluating $\int\frac{3+\cos(x)}{2-\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am  trying to find $$\int\frac{3+\cos(x)}{2-\cos(x)}dx$$
I did long division and got the **integrand** to be $$-(1+\frac{5}{\cos(x)-2})$$ To simplify the second term, I tried conjugate multiplication as well as Trigonometric Identities, but unable to proceed. Please help

Comment: This is what you need:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Comment: There are different methods of finding such integrals, including [online calculators](https://www.integral-calculator.com/). What are you looking for? Where is this exercise from?

Comment: When you don't know what to do with trigonometric functions involved, just apply $t=\tan x/2$

Comment: @user1046533 i got the questions from this site: https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/integration/100problems.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach: with the change of variables $\displaystyle u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ we have $\displaystyle u'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sec^{2}\frac{x}{2}$ and using $\displaystyle \sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^{2}+1}$ and $\displaystyle \cos(x)=\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}$ we can re-write the primitive as $\displaystyle 4\int\frac{u^{2}+2}{3u^{4}+4u^{2}+1}$ and using partial fraction we arrive to $\displaystyle \frac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)-x+C$ with $C$ be a constant of integration. Now, you can complete the details.

Answer (score 2):

Let given integral be $I$,
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{3+\cos x}{2-\cos x} dx \\
 &= \int \frac{5-(2-\cos x)}{2-\cos x} dx \\
 &=\int \frac{5}{2-\cos x} dx - \int dx \\
 &= 5 \int \frac{\sec^2\frac x2}{2(1+\tan^2\frac x2)- (1-\tan^2\frac x2）} dx - \int dx \tag{1}
\end{align*}
In the equation $(1)$ I've used formula of $\cos2x = \frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$.

Now let $ \tan(x/2) = t \implies \sec^2(x/2)dx = 2dt $,
\begin{align*} 
I &= 10\int \frac{1}{3t^2+1} dt - x \\
    &= \frac{10}{\sqrt3} \tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3t) - x + C\\
    &= \frac{10}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3}\tan\frac x2)- x + C
\end{align*}

Comment: Use `\cos` for $\cos$ and likewise for sec and tan. Also, some of your exponents need to be corrected. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you sir , I'm new so I don't know how to write properly. I'll see the link you gave.

Comment: I’ve helped you format the answer this time, you could also learn it here.

Comment: @Tianlalu Thank you Sir, I'm very thankful to you. For sure I'm gonna learn from here. :)